# streaming real time audio over UDP

Tags: python, sockets

I have been willing to develop an application which transmits real-time audio over a local network with the lowest latency possible in python.

So I ran into [this program](https://pyshine.com/How-to-send-audio-from-PyAudio-over-socket/) (the last UDP version) and I have been trying to tweak a few variables to achieve the lowest latency possible, which I guess can be pretty low in a `localhost` environment. However removing the 5 seconds wait time and reducing the `CHUNK` size down to 1024 still results in an audible latency.

Does the `BUFF_SIZE` and the sleep time of the `server_socket.sendto()` loop have to do with it?
Are they related to each other?

It seems that with a `BUFF_SIZE` lower than 4096 (which is approximately the latency that I experience) the client does not playback the stream.

Is it then related to the client's `queue`?

My MAIN QUESTION would be:
how do you fine tune these parameters to achieve the lowest latency possible?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reduce latency, use a smaller chunk size in your packets. When I worked on a well known voice over IP system years back, UDP packets only had between 30-90ms of audio in each.

> It seems that with a BUFF_SIZE lower than 4096 (which is approximately the latency that I experience) the client does not playback the stream.

That would be a bug in the client you need to investigate and address. Glancing at your code, I don't see an immediate issue. Nor do I see any debugging print/log statements revealing if packets are being received and have the expected payloads.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Indeed lowering the `CHUNK` size down to 64 brings down the latency! and I also finally understood that the `BUFF_SIZE` only sets the maximum amount of data that can be sent over to the client...but may I again take advantage of your expertise? how would you fine tune the transmission rate (i.e. the `time.sleep()` interval right...?) of the server? I  thought that `CHUNK/SAMPLE_RATE` would be appropriate, but it seems too slow...Is it relevant or should I put it "as low as possible" and handle the incoming data on the client?
Thank you very much again

Comment: ...is there some "entry level literature" that I could study?